# Does Harry Potter's original wand have a name?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

The most powerful wand was called the '*Elder Wand*'. But did the original wand Harry possess, made of holly and a phoenix feather core, have a name?

Comment: Harry's wand???

Comment: "A lot of people name their wands"......."A lot of wangs"

Comment: Order of the Stick strip #154, about naming Vaarsuvius's raven familiar, is slightly relevant. "I haven't named any of my other class features." http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0154.html

Comment: "Wand of the chosen one"?

Comment: It kinda seems awkward for the story to say "Death gave the man a thesthral core wand"

Comment: I ask a question and get -1? lol why? wtf I'm not marking any answers as accepted until someone explains why asking a question is worth -1

Comment: You're probably collecting more -1s because of your crap attitude in the edit. If you'd like to ask a question about how voting works, that's what the meta side of the site is for.

Comment: I know how voting works. It's probably not safe to ask questions in this forum anymore because people take offense if you want to find something out. But go ahead and hide behind story names and judge my awfully stupid question. Am I a muggle now?

Comment: @RobertAchmann I didn’t downvote, but if I had to guess why people were, it could be because we don’t hear anything about Harry’s wand being named in 7 books of following him around. People tend to downvote questions they think the answer to is easy to deduce.

Comment: If I had read all 7 books, I too wouldn't be asking the question. If I knew everything about space, I'd never ask NASA or Neil deGrasse Tyson anything. If I knew everything about finite math, I'd never ask how to use the Rational Roots Test to Find All Possible Roots. I don't know Harry Potter as well as the people here, so I thought I'd give it a go; perhaps someone would know. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## No, Harry and those around him never call his wand by a name.

Harry is the perspective character in a story told from a third-person limited perspective, meaning we know almost everything that goes on in Harry’s life and thoughts. Harry has never referred to his wand as anything other than his wand. Nor has anyone else named Harry’s wand for him.

## In fact, the Elder Wand is the *only* wand with a name we know of.

As far as we know, none of the wizards or witches we see throughout has *named* their wands. Many of them are quite fond of their wands, but at least to our knowledge, none of them call their wands by any special name (like Doombringer, Shirley, or Wandy McWandface). They either refer to their wands as simply their wands, or by a descriptor like “my black walnut wand” especially if they’ve had more than one wand.

The Elder Wand was named because it’s a wand of ancient legend, and supposedly extraordinary power, so it’s a special case.

However, it’s entirely possible that some wizards do name their wands and we just never hear of it.

Comment: I think Wandy would be upset, as it's last name is McWandface

Comment: @RobertAchmann Wandy can be happy now! :)

Answer (score 7):

The elder wand is known by a few names

> I sought a third wand, Severus. The Elder Wand, the Wand of Destiny, the Deathstick. <sub>*[Lord Voldemort](https://www.pottermore.com/quote/mastering-the-elder-wand)*</sub>

It seems wands are more generally described by their woods as is a more unique identifier than core or other [qualities](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126788/how-many-wands-were-chosen-for-pottermore) (38 woods, 21 lengths, 14 flexibility, 3 cores)

[Elder wood is the rarest of all:](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-woods)

> **The rarest wand wood of all, and reputed to be deeply unlucky, the elder wand is trickier to master than any other.** It contains powerful magic, but scorns to remain with any owner who is not the superior of his or her company; it takes a remarkable wizard to keep the elder wand for any length of time. The old superstition, ‘wand of elder, never prosper,’ has its basis in this fear of the wand, but in fact, the superstition is baseless, and those foolish wandmakers who refuse to work with elder do so more because they doubt they will be able to sell their products than from fear of working with this wood. The truth is that only a **highly unusual person will find their perfect match in elder**, and on the rare occasion when such a pairing occurs, I take it as certain that the witch or wizard in question is marked out for a special destiny. An additional fact that I have unearthed during my long years of study is that the owners of elder wands almost always feel a powerful affinity with those chosen by rowan.

While this does not imply the wand of oldest Peverell brother was the only wand made of elder (but it was supposedly the only wand made with Thestral hair), I would hazard a guess the legend behind it is what gave it the name.

Comment: The question is about Harry's wand, though - not the Elder Wand.

Answer (score 2):

### No. But there are descriptions.

> Harry's **first wand** was **11 inches long**. This was described by
> Garrick Ollivander to be an unusual combination of wand core and wood.
> The feather was donated by **Fawkes**, Albus Dumbledore's phoenix. It
> was revealed by Garrick Ollivander that Tom Riddle's wand core also
> came from Fawkes, making the two wands "brothers". Harry's wand was
> described as being "nice and supple".
> <sub>**http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter%27s_wand**</sub>

Throughout the books, there aren't any mentioned information about what is the name of Harry's wand is. But some people name their wands and it's up to them. But it's not necessary to do so for the main reason that it's *just a wand*.

### It's better for the *Tale of the Three Brothers* to have a name for the Elder wand.

> The eldest brother, a combative man, asked for a wand more powerful
> than any in existence. Death granted his wish by fashioning the Elder
> Wand from a branch of a nearby elder tree standing on the banks of the
> river. <sub>**TALE OF THE THREE BROTHERS**</sub> **

The **elder** wand could have been made to emphasize the power of **the most powerful wand.** And it suits the wand better to have a name especially that the story is like a **legend**.

### Elder brother's elder wand.

CORRECTION: as what @Skooba said, it's made from **elder wood**.

Comment: The wand was named the Elder wand because it is made of *elder wood*.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51445/does-elder-in-the-elder-wand-refer-to-the-wood-or-its-age

Comment: @Skooba : noted.